# PHP preg_replace regexp for dash

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace anything in the string that is not a letter, number, or dash "-".

How do I modify this line to include the dash?

```
$link = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', "", strtolower($_POST['link_name']));
```

Do I just insert it in there?

```
$link = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]/', "", strtolower($_POST['link_name']));
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to escape `-` since it's a special character for regexes:

```
$link = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-]/', '', strtolower($_POST['link_name']));
```

Answer (score 9):

Just add `-` to the end of the class (`[^a-z0-9-]`).

`-` has no special meaning at the end of a class. Alternatively, escape it with a backslash.